# Sink drain pipe won’t connect to trap

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, drain

Installing a new faucet in the bathroom.  The new drain pipe does not reach the trap. It is very close however. [image]

Comment: ok, so what is your question? ... what does a new faucet have to do with the drain pipe?

Comment: P.S.- the 1 1/2" x 1 1/4" reducing plastic slip-joint washer in your photo is upside-down.

Answer (score 1):

OK, you're going to need a drain pipe extension attached to your new drain pipe. Remove the blue protective tape.  It might just be easier to replace your pipe with a longer PVC pipe rather than having to cut your pipe to fit the extension in.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use your favorite internet search engine (or just walk into your favorite local plumbing supply house or home improvement center) and look for:

*sink tail pipe extension*

Purchase, assemble, cut off 90% of what you just bought, connect the trap to the remains of the extension.

The shortest one you'll probably find is 6". Since you only need about 6mm, you might want to cut off some of the purple tail piece so that you can actually attach the newly purchased extension, assemble it, then cut off most of the extension to slip it into the existing trap.